# Click on input inside button in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I got a button that when clicked, it shows a dropdown, and also, not only shows a dropdown but also lets the user change to a specific value by adding an input inside the button. I can't change this behavior since it's an RTE like tinyMCE, Summernote, etc. So the tool is added as a button.

Problem is, when trying to click on the input in Firefox, it bubbles up to the button so the event is swallowed by the parent button and not by the input. Chrome works fine, but Firefox is having an issue with `stopPropagation` looks like.

Here's a snippet so you can test it on Firefox & Chrome.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var input = document.getElementById('input');

button.onclick = function () {
    alert('button was pressed');
}
input.onclick = function (e) {
    
    e.stopPropagation();
    
    alert('input was pressed');
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="button()" id="button">button
    <input placeholder="input" onclick="input()" id="input"/>
</button>
```

Any workaround on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: e.preventDefault not working either ?

Comment: Yes, not working either. I'm using Firefox Quantum btw.

Comment: Are you sure the onClick is catched by the input field ? It seems like the focus is kept by the button ... I think the stopPropagation is not even fired !

Comment: yea, but how does it work on Chrome? looks like even though the input is getting the click event, is also "clicking" on the button, did you see that? but for some reason, is not bubbling up to button... but Firefox goes directly into the button, not on input when clicking.

Comment: If you just need a workaround, just extract the input field from the button ;)

Comment: I know, that would be the good solution, but for this case as i mentioned in the post, the RTE creates a button in the toolbar and i just wanted to add extra functionality to it.

Comment: You can modify in JS the toolbar to enhance it :)

Comment: Yea or i could create my own RTE library (? hahaha

Comment: Do you need the button's click event after you've clicked it once? If not, you can remove that so it won't capture that event anymore.

Comment: mmmm that's a good point, maybe i can try disabling it? Because it has a down arrow to open a dropdown, but i can disable it after showing the dropdown maybe.

Comment: @msqar yes disabling the button should still allow you to use the input within it.

Comment: K, let me check how it works, problem will be that if i want to close the dropdown by clicking the button again to make a toggle effect, i won't be able to do so.

Comment: What would save the input?

Comment: Font size change on Text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166120/discussion-between-emil-and-msqar).

Answer (score 1):

Placing an input inside of a button is not semantic HTML. Change the button to a `<div>` or a `<span>` and this should work properly. Sidenote - You will also run into this issue in IE.